# How to get the relevent table data using JOIN Query

Tags: php, sql, join

```
course{
    course_id,
    course_name,
}
subject{
    subject_id,
    subject_name,
    course_id

}
student{
    email,
    course_id,
}
```

This is my code , It display all the subjects belongs to the course

```
$_GET['email_address']=$_SESSION['email_address'];


$sql="(SELECT c.course_name course_name,su.subject_name subject_name 
   from subject su LEFT JOIN course c ON c.course_id=su.course_id) 
   UNION (SELECT c.course_name course_name,s.email_address email_address 
     from student s LEFT JOIN course c ON s.course_id=c.course_id
    WHERE s.email_address='".$_SESSION['email_address']."')";
```

When the course is done by "kamal@gmail.com", I want to get the all subjects belongs to the course which was done by "kamal@gmail.com", kamal@gmail.com is student email

The sample data are:

course:

```
course_id course_name
1         IT
2         Business
3         Design
```

subject:

```
subject_id subject_name course_id
111        html         1
222        java         1
333        Econ         2
444        Photoshop    3
```

student:

```
email           course_id
kamal@gmail.com 1
```

Then I want to get data which subjects belongs to course_id=1 do by kamal@gmail.com

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - all as well formatted text. Also tag the dbms you're using.

Comment: course{
    course_id,
    course_name,
}                                                                                                             course (1,IT), (2,Business), (3,Design)

Comment: subject{
    subject_id,
    subject_name,
    course_id

}                                                                                           subject(111,html,1), (222,java,1),(333,Econ,2),(444,Photoshop,3)

Comment: student{
    email,
    course_id,
}                                                                                   student(kamal@gmail.com,1)

Comment: Hey, not as comments. Edit the question instead!

Comment: I edit the question

Comment: As a general notice: It is better to use convention of table naming. i.e `course` should be `courses` and `course_id` in courses table should be `id`, and `course_name` to be `name` etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of joins is all you need

```
select su.subject_name, course_name
from student st
inner join subject su
  on su.course_id = st.course_id
inner join course co
  on co.course_id = st.course_id
where st.email = 'kamal@gmail.com'
```

Answer (score 0):

What about the following?

```
SELECT C.COURSE_NAME, SU.SUBJECT_NAME, S.EMAIL
FROM COURSE C
INNER JOIN SUBJECT SU ON SU.COURSE_ID = C.COURSE_ID
INNER JOIN STUDENT S ON S.COURSE_ID = C.COURSE_ID
WHERE S.EMAIL = 'kamal@gmail.com'
```

Answer (score 0):

> Here is the **suggestion** for database design about your question

**Table :** **`courses`** Has many `subjects`

```
+-----------+-------------+---------------------+
| course_id | course_name | created             |
+-----------+-------------+---------------------+
|         1 | CSS         | 2017-03-20 14:21:34 |
|         2 | HTML        | 2017-03-20 14:21:39 |
|         3 | JS          | 2017-03-20 14:21:44 |
|         4 | PHP         | 2017-03-20 14:21:50 |
+-----------+-------------+---------------------+
```

**Table :** **`students`** Has many `courses`

```
+------------+--------------+------------------+---------------------+
| student_id | student_name | email            | created             |
+------------+--------------+------------------+---------------------+
|          1 | Student 1    | kamal@gmail.com  | 2017-03-20 14:19:32 |
|          2 | Student 2    | kamal2@gmail.com | 2017-03-20 14:19:32 |
+------------+--------------+------------------+---------------------+
```

**Table :** **`subjects`** Belongs to `courses`

```
+------------+-----------+--------------+---------------------+
| subject_id | course_id | subject_name | created             |
+------------+-----------+--------------+---------------------+
|          1 |         1 | A            | 2017-03-20 14:20:56 |
|          2 |         1 | B            | 2017-03-20 14:21:12 |
|          3 |         2 | C            | 2017-03-20 14:21:22 |
+------------+-----------+--------------+---------------------+
```

**Table :** **`courses_students`** Many To Many `courses` `students`

```
+----+-----------+------------+---------------------+
| id | course_id | student_id | created             |
+----+-----------+------------+---------------------+
|  1 |         1 |          1 | 2017-03-20 14:44:42 |
|  2 |         2 |          2 | 2017-03-20 14:44:42 |
|  3 |         2 |          1 | 2017-03-20 14:44:42 |
+----+-----------+------------+---------------------+
```

> **Note :** `courses` has many Students, `students` Has many `courses`. This is mapping table.

**MySQL Query :**

```
SELECT
  students.student_name,
  courses.course_name,
  subjects.subject_name
FROM
  `students`
LEFT JOIN
  courses_students ON students.student_id = courses_students.student_id
LEFT JOIN
  subjects ON subjects.course_id = courses_students.course_id
INNER JOIN
  courses ON courses.course_id = courses_students.course_id
WHERE
  students.email = 'kamal@gmail.com'
```

**MySQL Query result :**

```
+--------------+-------------+--------------+
| student_name | course_name | subject_name |
+--------------+-------------+--------------+
| Student 1    | CSS         | A            |
| Student 1    | CSS         | B            |
| Student 1    | HTML        | C            |
+--------------+-------------+--------------+
```